# Keep Chrome's "Inspect Element" changes upon page navigation

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on a website and I am changing some CSS rules in page "A" via Chrome's "Inspect Element" to see how the page look. The thing is, when I navigate to other page, and then come back to page "A", changes are gone.

Is there a way to keep those changes for my current browser (Chrome) session? I understand that those changes are not permanent and that I am the only one that sees those changes, but I would like to keep those changes even if I navigate away from the page and come back.

Moreover, I don't mind if I have to use a different browser such as Firefox.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you not just open the other page in a different tab/window?

Comment: That is not an option for what I need :/

Comment: You could write an addon that saves all styles of all elements and applies them when you come back to the page.

Comment: Do you know is there such addon by any chance already available somewhere?

Comment: they have introduced the new thing called "local override " in chrome